# GWT RequestFactory STRANGE behavior : No error reporting

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt, hsqldb, requestfactory

I do have a problem, and I can't figure out what it happens...
GWT beginner, working on a personal project.

Environment:

- **maven** project with **two modules**

  - one module is the '**model**', and has **Hibernate**, **HSQLDB** and **Spring** dependencies. HSQLDB runs **embedded**, in memory, configured from spring applicationContext.xml
  - the other module is the 'web' and has all **GWT dependencies**

The application is built using some Spring Roo generated code as basis, later modified and extended.

The issue is that, when **editing** some entity fields and pressing save, nothing happens. No problem when creating a new entity instance, **only on edit** changing some field and pressing '**save**' basically overrides the new values.
So I started to thoroughly debug the client code, enabled hibernate and Spring detailed logging, but still ... nothing.

Then I made a surprising (for me) discovery.
Inspecting the GWT response payload, I have seen this:

```
    {"S":[false],"O":        [{"T":"663_uruC_g7F5h5IXBGvTP3BBKM=","V":"MS4w","S":"IjMi","O":"UPDATE"}],"I":[{"F":true,"M":"Server Error: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myvdm.server.domain.Document; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myvdm.server.domain.Document"}]}
```

Aha, detached entity passed to persist !!!
Please note that the gwt client code uses this snippet to call the service:

> requestContext.persist().using(proxy);

Arguably this could trigger the exception, and calling merge() could solve the problem, however, read on, to question 3...

Three question arise now:

- Why isn't this somehow sent to the client as an error/exception?
- Why isn't this logged by Hibernate?
- How come the Spring Roo generated code (as I said, used as basis) works without manifesting this problem?

Thanks a lot,

Avaiting for some opinions/suggestions.

---

**EDITED AFTER T. BROYER's RESPONSE::**

Hi Thomas, thanks for the response.

I have a custom class that implements RequestTransport and implements send(). This is how I collected the response payload. Implementation follows::

```
public void send(String payload, final TransportReceiver receiver) {
    TransportReceiver myReceiver = new TransportReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onTransportSuccess(String payload) {
            try {
                receiver.onTransportSuccess(payload);
            } finally {
                eventBus.fireEvent(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent.State.RECEIVED));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransportFailure(ServerFailure failure) {
            try {
                receiver.onTransportFailure(failure);
            } finally {
                eventBus.fireEvent(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent.State.RECEIVED));
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        wrapped.send(payload, myReceiver);
    } finally {
        eventBus.fireEvent(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent.State.SENT));
    }
}
```

Here's the code that is executed when 'save' button is clicked in edit mode:

```
RequestContext requestContext = editorDriver.flush();
    if (editorDriver.hasErrors()) {
        return;
    }

    requestContext.fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
            if (editorDriver != null) {
                setWaiting(false);
                super.onFailure(error);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void ignore) {
            if (editorDriver != null) {
                editorDriver = null;
                exit(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> errors) {
            if (editorDriver != null) {
                setWaiting(false);
                editorDriver.setConstraintViolations(errors);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Based on what you said, onSuccess() should be called, and it's called**

So how do I isolate exactly the code that creates the problem? I have this method that creates a fresh request context in order to persist the object

```
        @Override
        protected RequestContext createSaveRequestContextFor(DocumentProxy proxy) {
            DocumentRequestContext request = requests.documentRequestContext();
            request.persist().using(proxy);
            return request;
        }
```

and this is how it is called::

```
 editorDriver.edit(getProxy(), createSaveRequestContextFor(getProxy()));
```

As for the Spring problem, you are saying that, between two subsequent requests, the find() and persist(), the JPA entityManager should not be closed. I am still investigating this, but after I press the edit button, I see the message 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager' and that  is not right, maybe the @Transactional annotation is not applied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't this somehow sent to the client as an error/exception?

It is. The `"S": [false]` indicates the first (and only) method invocation (remember, a `RequestContext` is a batch!) has failed. The `onFailure` method of the invocation's `Receiver` will be called.

The `"F": true` of the `ServerFailure` then says it's a *fatal* error, so the default implementation of `Receiver#onFailure` would throw a `RuntimeException`. However, as you do not use a `Receiver` at all, nothing happens and the error is silently ignored.

Note that the batch request in itself has succeeded, so the global `Receiver` (the one you'd pass to `RequestContext#fire`) would have its `onSuccess` method called.
Also note that `Request#fire(Receiver)` is a shorthand for `Request#to(Receiver)` followed by `RequestContext#fire()` (with no argument).

> Why isn't this logged by Hibernate?

This I don't know, sorry.

> How come the Spring Roo generated code (as I said, used as basis) works without manifesting this problem?

OK, let's explore the underlying reason of the exception: the entity is loaded by your `Locator` (or the entity class's `findXxx` static method) and then the `persist` method is called on the instance. If you do not use the same JPA `EntityManager` / Hibernate session in the `find` and `persist` methods, then you'll have the issue.
Request Factory expects you to use the *open session in view* pattern to overcome this. I unfortunately do not know what kind of code Spring Roo generates.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the *open session in view* pattern Thomas mentioned, just add this filter definitions to your `web.xml` to turn on the pattern in your Spring application:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>
        Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Right, thanks Ümit, I found the problem, and it was due to some malformed configuration files...However, one question still remains open, why isn't Hibernate reporting any errors? On something like this, I should surely see a stack trace...

Comment: I can't remember 100% but I have a similar setup Hibernate + JPA2 + Requestfactory and when I ran into that issue I believe there was an exception thrown in the save method and I got it logged in the GWT's console. Not sure if my Spring app also logged it.